# Set JLabel size so when drag and resize window it doesn't resize

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

i'm working on this little project for school. I need a kind of-control panel with the current state of two FIFO's, also current time and a couple more things. I got it, but, i need more space for the FIFO's than for the other data. How can i make those three JLabel's stick to the top and let the other one more space?

Here is the code for the JFrame and JLabels:

```
    // Control panel
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panel de control");
    // Acces the pane
    Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
    // One JLabel per data
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[4];
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 1, 1));
    /* CURRENT TIME */
    label[0] = new JLabel("Hora actual");
    label[0].setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
    label[0].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label[0].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    /* REQUEST SERVER STATUS */
    label[1] = new JLabel("Servidor peticiones");
    label[1].setText("Aceptacion de peticiones: ACTIVADO");
    label[1].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label[1].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    /* NUMBER OF CLIENTS */
    label[2] = new JLabel("Clientes atendidos");
    label[2].setText("Clientes siendo atendidos: 0");
    label[2].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label[2].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    /* FIFO's STATUS */
    label[3] = new JLabel("Estado de las colas");
    String colas = "<HTML><p style=\"text-align:center\">Cola de la valla 0 (Pequeña)<br><br>Cola de la valla 1 (Grande)</p></HTML>";
    label[3].setText(colas);
    label[3].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label[3].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.NORTH);
    frame.setLocation(60, 0); // desplazar ventana 60 pixeles
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
        panel.add(label[i]);
    }

    frame.setSize(400, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

And this is is how it looks like one initialized and with some data on the FIFO's:
(Can't post pics, so here is the plane link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnrZB.png

Comment: Use a GridBagLayout if you want more flexible control over how different components get sized.

Comment: Why is this tagged CSS?